# при вызове npm появляется окно Welcome to Node.js v18.16.1

Tags: node.js, npm

при вызове npm появляется окно Welcome to Node.js v18.16.1. И не реагирует не на что, просто открывается другое такое же окно, пробовал переустанавливать ноут и устанавливать заново node.js что делать ?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Как вы npm запускаете?

Comment: https://github.com/nodejs/help/issues/3990